# How to extract label value pairs from json Solr response in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, solr, getjson

I am using getJson to call a Solr service which gives me a response that includes

```
{
"contentDate":[
  "Second World War",
  179,
  "First World War",
  16,
  "Pre-1914",
  12,
  "All Periods",
  5,
  "Interwar",
  1
]
}
```

The problem is that each value should correspond to the previous label, but when I try to extract them I just get a single array with ten values.

Is there a specific way I could extract them as label/value pairs?

EDIT: I've now got this working by testing if it's an odd or even item, storing the array contents when even, then constructing the label/value pairs when it's odd. See http://jsfiddle.net/jamesinealing/qevscxn1/

But surely there's a more elegant way? Maybe not given the way that this endpoint responds.